# ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and 32. Shapes are [3,3,128,32] and [3,3,32,9]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-processing, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm trying to build a model to perform reconstruction of speech by feeding image frames from a video. But during the prediction, I got the error. Please help me resolve the error.

ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and 32. Shapes are [3,3,128,32] and [3,3,32,9]. for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [3,3,128,32], [3,3,32,9].

THIS IS THE ERROR.

GIVEN BELOW ARE THE OTHER SET OF WARNINGS:

[List of certain other warnings along with ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlwTy.jpg)
PLEASE HELP ME RESOLVE THIS ISSUE AT THE EARLIEST.

Comment: Please share your code as well as model code and inputs' dimensions (what is model expecting and what are you feeding). That will help to better understand where you messed up and easier for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect shapes error, it tells you that the input tensors must be equal in shape, though the error message does not provide enough info on what is the correct dimensions for the model you are using you can try reshaping to each dimension and check the output to confirm it worked correctly.

You can use cv2 for reshape the image before converting it to tensor, this is a sample code using cv2, First make sure you have opencv installed and imported like this:

```
import cv2
```

Then you can resize the image like this:

```
resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 32))
```

And then use `resized_img` as input.

Cheers!